# Initializing struct seg fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm initializing a struct which represents a hash table. I'm attempting to make the frequencies = 0 and the keys = null, but I'm getting a seg fault and not too sure why.
Here is my code:

```
htable htable_new(int capacity) {
  int i;

  htable result = emalloc(sizeof *result);
  result->capacity = capacity;
  result->frequencies = emalloc(capacity * sizeof result->frequencies[0]);
  result->keys = emalloc(capacity * sizeof result->keys[0]);
  for (i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
    result->frequencies[i] = 0;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
    result->keys[i] = NULL;
  }

  return result;
}
```

and here is the struct which I'm initializing:

```
struct htablerec {

  int capacity;
  int num_keys;
  int *frequencies;
  char **keys;

};
```

I don't see what's wrong as I'm trying to initialize all the int's i've allocated to 0,
and all the char pointers to NULL. Is this wrong? Should I be doing this some other way?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: In what moment segfault occurs?

Comment: Apparently at the line "for(i = 0; i < capacity; i++)"

Comment: Pretty sure it's the second.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (notice pointers near result and return type):

```
htable *htable_new(int capacity) {
  int i;

  htable *result = emalloc(sizeof *result);
  result->capacity = capacity;
  result->frequencies = emalloc(capacity * sizeof result->frequencies[0]);
  result->keys = emalloc(capacity * sizeof result->keys[0]);
  for (i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
    result->frequencies[i] = 0;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
    result->keys[i] = NULL;
  }

  return *result;
}
```

Or, as far as your structure is small, you may want to return it by value:

```
htable htable_new(int capacity) {
  int i;
  htable result = { 0 };

  result.capacity = capacity;
  result.frequencies = emalloc(capacity * sizeof result->frequencies[0]);
  result.keys = emalloc(capacity * sizeof result->keys[0]);
  for (i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
    result.frequencies[i] = 0;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
    result.keys[i] = NULL;
  }

  return result;
}
```

I changed `result` to be an actual struct, rather than pointer to it. Because of that, it's allocated on stack, fields are initialized as usual and then I return it as is. That means, all struct will be copied to the new place.

Remember that only field of `htable` are copied; `capacity` and `keys` are copied as pointers. That means that if you do `htable a = new_htable(10); htable b = a;` then `a.keys == b.keys` (they point to the same array).

I don't know, how your code compiled at all. By the way, you forgot to initialize `num_keys` field and the name of struct you defined doesn't match the name of return type.

Comment: Ah yes I did forget to initialize num_keys. As to your second point. I used typedef struct htablerec *htable; in another file.

Comment: I'm quite new to C, would you be able to describe what you have done in the second part?

Comment: I have expanded the answer.

Comment: When I tried the second way, I got the warning - ISO C forbids empty initializer braces

Comment: Just put `0` in brackets.